# How to determine if passing in an object is better than several parameters (int, string, etc)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, oop

I have a class/object called "User" that has about a dozen properties (eg: UserGUID, UserName, etc.). It has a constructor, static methods, couple other helpers/support methods, etc.

The website has hundreds of functions/methods where 2+ parameters come from the User object. For example:

```
public string HelloWorld(Guid userGUID, Guid accountGUID, bool somethingElse)
{
    //Do something
}
```

I really want to pass in the User object itself to make the call cleaner and not have to keep adding parameters everytime I need a new value from the User object. Like this:

```
public string HelloWorld(User user)
{
    //Do something
    Guid userGUID = user.UserGUID;
}
```

So my question is, at what point is passing in the object good/bad vs passing in several parameters?  Does it depend on the size of the object? How would I determine what's "too big" vs "OK"?  Is it the number of parameters? How many params is too many?

Comment: This probably should (and probably will) be closed as primarily opinion-based.  That said, my two cents are that objects (particularly those represented by interfaces) allow for variance, expansion of the API without severe costs to the invoker, and better encapsulation.  Use objects more and use them sooner rather than later.

Comment: So there's no negative performance passing an object (even a large object) to a method vs passing in several/many parameters?

Comment: In your case use parameters. It is cleaner and independent. One can easily see what he needs to provide as arguments. For second choice it is better to do  when function is fully dependent on User object. in your case it just using some

Comment: @Losbear passing object will just copy reference of object. So it is ok. But I not reccomend it as I mentioned above.

Comment: @Losbear is User object is your viewmodel ?

Comment: No, not my ViewModel - All my controllers inherit from a custom 'base controller' that has a property "m_CurrentUser" that is this User object.  The m_CurrentUser is used by the Actions to get request-related data, including loading ViewModels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Clean Code, Robert Martin says to prefer 0 arguments, 1 or 2 arguments are acceptable and 3 is too many.

In my opinion as long as you're in the same process I think passing the object is preferable to passing arguments.  You wouldn't want to send (or receive) more than is needed to another process (say a web service).

I highly recommend Clean Code, it's a good read and has a lot to say about structure.

Comment: I'll have a look into "Clean Code" - sounds interesting.  I'm leaning towards leaving params in place based on what you, qwr & Travis said - primarily on the basic principle that effeciency is lost anytime you pass more than you are going to use. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

You should think about *what the method is supposed to do* . Why does the method exist?

The semantic of the method will determine its arguments. So, for example, if `HelloWord` is supposed to print some stuff out, like a `userId`, and `something else`, then the signature should contain `userId` and `something else` as arguments.

On the other hand, if `HelloWord` is supposed to print out some information about a `User`, then the method signature should have the object User as a parameter.

It all depends on the method semantic.

Comment: Understood, but it's not that simple. Some methods are simple methods that return a single value but need several params to contruct that value.  Other methods do a bunch fo things (eg; build reports, etc) that is determined by the params passed in.  Some methods keep getting improved upon - clients keep asking for new features to be added, but in order to make the method do it, i now have to add yet another param, etc.  That's why i'm trying to determine what's the "breaking point"

Comment: Each method should do one - and only one - thing. So if you have methods doing 100 differents things with 20 parameters being passed, something is wrong. Try to unit test your methods, that'll help you think about the model of your code

Answer (score 1):

There is a very important difference here, and this is not an opinion.

> I have a class/object called "User" that has about a dozen properties

Given the above situation, if you were then to allow `(User user)` as opposed to only allowing `(Guid userGUID, Guid accountGUID, bool somethingElse)` you have just introduced a security hole.

Clients would be able to send more data than they were supposed to have access to by posting the extra names of the `User` class. For example, it is possible for a client to alter foreign navigation property keys in this fashion if you make the entire class available (and it had foreign relations). It is also possible for clients to alter timestamps, and even logical separations depending on information stored in that class.

Preventing this type of breach is easy to do if you allow the entire class to be accepted, you just need to then manually inspect each property to make sure it wasn't erroneously sent, or screen it by only selecting the subset of information sent. Either way, this is a bad idea.

While there may be no difference in using a `User` class with the same properties as the 3 shown, allowing the model binding of a `User` class which has a larger set than the 3 can be problematic if left unchecked.

Comment: In the case of my User object, an instance of the object is only created after the user's cookie has been read, decrypted & authenticated against my datasource. The User object is then only used on backend to process the request, so it's highly unlikely it'll be hacked or injected. But I do hear your point regarding giving the method "more power" than it needs - which could introduce problems down the road.  Thanks for the input!

Comment: @Losbear - Authenticated clients are the ones with the most access to cause problems.